# Instantiation of Inner Class

Tags: java, class, object, inline, instantiation

In the following code, how can I reach the inner class 'wheel'?

```
public class InstantiateClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car c = new Car();
    //not sure how to get an instance of 'Wheel' here 
}

}

class Car{
public static class Wheel{

}
}
```

Comment: I'd regard non-private nested classes (not an inner class in this case) with suspicion.

Answer (score 4):

```
Car.Wheel w = new Car.Wheel();
```

should do the trick.